# Animate div tag when button is pressed in css3 transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a div tag and a button. What I want is when I press the button then I want the div tag to be animated using css3 transition. My current code rotates button when I press the button because I am applying transform to button. How can I make my following code work just like I wanted?

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F76Nm/)

```
<button>Button</button>
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

CSS styles

```
.rotate {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: green;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
}

button:active {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: You need js to add a class to the div.rotate when the button is clicked

Comment: I need css3 pure solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `+` for select adjacent siblings

```
button:active + div.rotate {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/F76Nm/3/)

For further detail about adjacent sibling selector visit [**here**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/adjacent#Adjacent_sibling_combinator_A_.2B_B)

Comment: How would I do that with previous one, lets say `div.rotate` is before the button?

Comment: in that case you can't do it with pure css

Comment: Is it possible to stop it going back to original position? Now when I press the button the it animates but when I release the button the div tag moves back to its original position.

Answer (score 1):

try this use Use ***+*** if it's an adjacent sibling

```
.rotate  {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: green;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
}
  div
   {
webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;  
   }
 button:active + div {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `button:active` to `button:active + .rotate` or `button:active ~ .rotate`

Use `+` if it's an adjacent sibling or `~` if it's further down the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to achieve this is using a more permanent pseudo class to trigger the change, for instance the focus one.

And, if you want the change to persist only with CSS, there is a hack for this (that even has *name*; but I can't remember it now), that is making the back transition hugely delayed

```
.rotate {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 9999s ease 9999s;
}

button:focus + div.rotate {
        transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/F76Nm/6/)